# AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I upgraded numpy to the latest version and now I am getting following error on importing numpy:

> AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute
>   '**array_function**'

I am using numpy version 1.16.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uninstall all installs of Numpy using

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

for python3

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

You may need to run the uninstall command several times since several versions of numpy may be installed.  Then run

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: this should fix it 

Comment: I got this error when I upgraded numpy, simply uninstalling numpy fixed this error, but what I don't understand here is that when I uninstalled numpy it didn't remove from the packages listed under "settings->proect Interpreter" and without installing numpy again it fixed the error. :/

Comment: Turns out I had to call 'pip uninstall numpy' multiple times for multiple versions :-)

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an ongoing issue (with the recent release of Numpy `1.16.0` there was a rash of related bug reports). There's a whole bunch more info about the causes of and fixes for this bug on an [issue thread on Numpy's Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12736).

## The problem

As described in the issue, the problem is caused by path conflicts between the files of different Numpy versions. They also suggest that there may be an issue with older versions of `pip` (specifically, there used to be an issue with how `pip` uninstalled (or failed to uninstall) old versions of Numpy).

## The fix

The Numpy dev recommend fix is to first upgrade your `pip`:

```
pip install -U pip
```

then uninstall/reinstall the latest version of Numpy (this does both in a single command):

```
pip install -U numpy
```

## If that doesn't work

Some people ended up having stranger path conflicts that they were unable to resolve just by reinstalling with `pip`. If the above steps fail, check to see if you have any old installs of Numpy anywhere on your filesystem. If you do, get rid of them and then try reinstalling Numpy again.